# why linux search path for .so when it already searched the .so succeed in another path?

Tags: linux, unix

it seems odd to me.
i put the path "`/home/nemo/foxyserver_strace_opt/lib`" in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as first path to search.

and then i use strace to trace my program. it shows below:

```
10695 16:12:58.227132 open("/home/nemo/foxyserver_strace_opt/lib/tls/x86_64/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3 <0.000018>
10695 16:12:58.227486 open("/home/nemo/foxyserver_strace_opt/lib/tls/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3 <0.000023>
10695 16:12:58.227937 open("/home/nemo/foxyserver_strace_opt/lib/x86_64/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3 <0.000018>
10695 16:12:58.228360 open("/home/nemo/foxyserver_strace_opt/lib/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3 <0.000016>
```

see? the libselinux.so.1 is search successful.it is right on the path "`/home/nemo/foxyserver_strace_opt/lib`".

and then i continue to see below:

```
11144 16:13:01.536915 open("/home/nemo/foxyserver/server/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000014>
11144 16:13:01.537058 open("/home/nemo/foxyserver/extra/lib/tls/x86_64/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3 <0.000021>
11144 16:13:01.537391 open("/home/nemo/foxyserver/extra/lib/tls/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3 <0.000019>
11144 16:13:01.537679 open("/home/nemo/foxyserver/extra/lib/x86_64/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3 <0.000019>
11144 16:13:01.537990 open("/home/nemo/foxyserver/extra/lib/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3 <0.000017>
11144 16:13:01.538469 open("/lib64/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3 <0.000014>
```

see? linux search a new path "`/home/nemo/foxyserver/extra/lib/x86_64/`" for `libselinux.so.1` again even though it can search the path "`/home/nemo/foxyserver_strace_opt/lib`".

why?

Comment: BTW, does it proceed further without errors, or does it stop and complain that it can't find that shared object? If so, what's that exact error message?